# Cant boot into OS using YUMI multi boot from USB

Tags: installation

I formatted my 16GB USB to FAT32.

Downloaded YUMI Multi Boot and installed UBUNTU 13.10 & BACKTRACK5

1. I was getting `No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found! boot: _` error. 
   So I changed folder name and two files to SYSLINUX and error is gone.
2. Once I try to load either OS screen flashes black and nothing happens.

Any suggestions?!

Goal: Is to be able to dual boot into Ubuntu and Backtrack as well as have a partition for personal files. I also want to be able to download tools and make changes to Ubuntu and keep those changes.

BTW: Im a noob trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [contacting the publisher](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/contact/) of YUMI Multi Boot since the BACKTRACK5 distro is [not yet supported](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/). Some distros, sad to say, don't work well with multi-booting from a USB FlashDrive.